# Using AsyncTask with Lists containing objects of different types

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am using AsyncTask to get data from an API. I have the list in the onPostExecute method like below, and It is populated with the data I need.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(List<Item> items) {
    Log.d("Here", Integer.toString(items.size()));       
}
```

However, I want to reuse the AsyncTask class to perform other API calls which will return Lists containing objects of different types.

How do i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

you have to make sure you make different async objects each time you make an API call since you can't just call the same object the second time.

Other than that you can return List of Objects and parse it back

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(List<Object> items) {
    //here cast it back to desired object/ pojo      
}
```

or just return String

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String items) {
    //use Gson to parse it back to desired object / pojo     
}
```

For more info on [Gson](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaLibrary-Gson/article.html)